# round corners text area box either in javascript or in css

Tags: javascript, css

can anyone suggest me for a round corners text area box either in javascript or in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "classic" way to do this, is using a background-image on a div around the textarea and setting border/outline of the textarea to none, like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url(image/with/rounded/corners.png);">
    <textarea style="border: none; outline: none;">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

CSS3 supports rounded corners, but that is not well supported, see e.g. http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

**EDIT:** The answer was correct at that time, but `border-radius` in IE is only supported from version 9 on.

Comment: CSS3 rounded corners is well supported.

Answer (score 2):

I use [jQuery Corner](http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/). It applies css3 corners to the browsers that support them and draws corners for the browsers that don't (IE).

Answer (score 0):

Rounded corners could be done with Rico: http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/08/10/rounded-corners-with-rico/, a JS library in addition to the JQuery plugin mentioned in the other post.

Or, you can do rounded corners with teh AjaxControlToolkit RoundedCornersExtender: http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/RoundedCorners/RoundedCorners.aspx