# Custom Textarea/texbox and scroll

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, customization

I need to customize an HTML textarea (put round corners) and costumize his respective horizontal scrollbar. Ive search for a js/jquery plugin but the closest that I have found was this:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

but this one does not work on textareas, only in Div elements.

Comment: A really good answer for rounded corners is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154383/round-corners-text-area-box-either-in-javascript-or-in-css).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a bug of it maybe.
But there is a work-around.

### Workaround

If it works on a `<div>`, then why don't you use a `<div>` as a `<textarea>`?

```
<div id="textarea_1" contentEditable="true"><p>Blah</p></div>

<script>
     var ele=$("div#textarea_1")[0]; //Make it a textarea-like when it is a <div>
     if('contentEditable' in ele){
         ele.contentEditable=true;   //Turn it on
     }else if('designMode' in ele){
         ele.designMode="on";        //For older Firefox versions
     }

    var value=$("div#textarea_1>p").html();
    console.log(value)  //The value is here
    //please look at the demo below for more...
</script>
```

See it for yourself: ***[Working demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PvJXu/3/)*** *(includes round corners, works on all popular browsers)*

### Better plugin?

Personally, I think ***[this one](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)*** also works good at customizing scroll bars.
It lets you to apply CSS style on it.

See it for yourself: ***[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/t6HaM/)***

### CSS3 Maybe?

Maybe it's the time to use CSS3.
Read more ***[here](http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/)***.

--> ***[Demo](http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html)***

Hope this helps you out.